# Blocking assignment to a logic inside task in sv

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to do the execute the below code but i see that value2 is not getting updated as expected.previous value of value1 is retained in value2.

```
class a;
  logic [31:0] value1,value2;

  task a;
    for(i=0;i<=width;i=i+1)
    begin
      @(vif.clk)

      value[0]=`vif.si;
      value=value<<1;
    end
  endtask

  value2=value1;

endclass
```

what could be the alternative for this plz let me know.

Comment: Please use code tags. And it is very bad programming practices to have a task name (or any property name) given the same name as the class name it is defined in. `a`

Comment: The statement value2=value1; is not legal. This would never compile. Please show the code you are executing.

Comment: Hi all,the problem is resolved.I used a temp variable to store the previous value and when the loop iterates for the last time im writing in to transaction item.and i see expected value.I have to be careful while using Blocking assignments.Thanks all for your valueable comments.:)

Answer (score 1):

Your code example isn't complete. I guess you are defining the line ' value2=value1; ' inside a class body. This isn't a continuous assignment as you are probably use to from modules. This just means it will define a field called value2 (of type wire I think) and set its initial value to the value of the field 'value' (I assume you meant value because I see no reference to value1).

The fact that you want to use blocking assignments means that if you want to store the previous value of 'value' in value2 you have to do it in task 'a'. You can't do it from some other parallel thread as you don't know in which order they get called. Example:

```
task a();
  value2 = value; // save value and then proceed to update it
  for(i=0;i<=width;i=i+1) begin 
    @(vif.clk);
    value[0]=vif.si;
    value=value<<1;
  end
endtask
```

Comment: Hi i am assigning the value value2 =value after the for loop.but once the for loop completes the updated or current data is not assigned to the value2.instead previous value is retained.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the line value2=value does not mean that you assign after the for loop completed.